# How to get some specific data from a string using php?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have three string as like below. I can get one string at a time from a sports website, the string format might be in 3 different ways or it could be any other way. But the string must have the same information.

```
(all out; 71.2 overs; 291 mins)
(all out; 129.1 overs)
(5 wickets dec; 97 overs)
```

I wanted to extract below data from those string using PHP. How can I do it?

```
$wicket = 10; //if all out
$over = 71;
$ball = 2; //it will be 0 if over doesn't have floating number
```

Comment: unclear, where do `$wicket = 10` and `$ball = 2` values come from?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest value comes from the above mentioned strings. Those strings will come from a json file.

Comment: show the actual input which contain values `10` and `2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are wanting to use the stristr() function. This will search a string for a proved string.

Convert the JSON to an array and loop to populate $providedString below.

```
$dataFromSomewhere = /* ... */;
$returnValue =0

foreach ($dataFromSomeWhere as $key => $value) {
    echo $value; # would be, for exp: `(5 wickets dec; 97 overs)`

    if (stristr($value, 'wickets')) {
        $returnValue += 10;
    } elseif (stristr($value, 'overs')) {
        $returnValue += 5;
    }
}
echo $returnValue; # would be, for exp: 15
```

As for $ball check the score value for the `.` or try to cast as a decimal/double and check if it does (boolean check).

Comment: Can you please take one input from those three as an input string and make the code in [link](http://phpfiddle.org/) ?